# how to change postgresql sequence maximum value

Tags: postgresql

I have following sequence created
CREATE SEQUENCE public.test_seq
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 2147483647
START 1
CACHE 1
NO CYCLE;
once it is created, i want to change the maximum value ?
do i need to alter the name and create a same name sequence with maximum value ?

Comment: ALTER SEQUENCE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
alter sequence test_seq maxvalue 99999;
```